# wattage consumption of three phase electric motor

Tags: power, motor, ac, watts

i have a 5 hp motor in my factory . at load, it shows 3.5 ampere consumption ( when tested by a meter). is the consumption accurate? someone told me that 5 hp three phase motor will consume 7.5 ampere. what will be the unit consumption if it consumes 3.5 ampere. a detailed reply would be appreciated. thanks

Comment: Please add little bit details more, like type of motor; Voltage rating; nature of load; . if you give this details it easy to give the specific answer or otherwise need to write an essay

Comment: Is the 3.5A the current on one phase? What voltage is the motor using?

Comment: this is a three phase motor, running on 440 volts

Comment: 1 HP = 745.7W, so on a rough calc 5HP = 3728W. Is that 440V phase to phase?  You can work out your current back from that.

Comment: Was the motor working fully loaded when you measured 3.5A? It may be 3.5A lightly loaded and 7.5A under normal (5HP) load.

Comment: It sounds like your motor is running at about half of its rated load, which is about right for an industrial application, especially if it needs to start up under load. If you want a detailed reply, you need to ask a detailed question.

Answer (score 1):

Most 3-phase motors used in factories have rating plates (nameplates) that list the name of the manufacturer, rated voltage, rated frequency, full-load current, full-load power factor, full load speed and other information. To estimate the power usage, that information would be helpful. If the type of enclosure is not listed, it can be determined by looking at the motor. You may be able to obtain performance data from the manufacturer's website or request it.

Here is data for a similar motor at 440V:

No load: 3.1A, 0.15kW

1/4 load: 3.6A, 1.1kW

1/2 load: 4.4A, 2.1kW

3/4 load: 5.5A, 3.1kW

Full load: 6.9A, 4.2kW

For most 3-phase induction motors, the no-load current is between 30% and 50% of full-load current.

Answer (score -1):

Assume that V=440v and A=3.1 in three phase supply.
Then the power consumption is the following, assuming efficiency is 100%.

P(kWH) = V*I*√3/1000 = 440*3.1*1.732/1000 = 2.36 kWH

For 5Hp = 5*2.36 = 11.8 kWH

For 24 hours = 24*11.8 = 283.2 kWH

For 30 days = 30*283.2 = 8496 kWH (or) 8496 units

If electricity charge per unit is Rs.9 then Cost = 9*8496 =76464 Rupees

Cost maybe differ based on efficiency....

Comment: Welcome to EE.SE but your answer is confused and incorrect. Power is measured in kW. Energy is power x time and is measured in kWh.

Comment: (The symbol for hour is h. hp isn't *hours peak*, but *horse power*: the power needed to lift 75 litres of water by one meter in one second under "normal conditions".)